# i want to filter my cards using tags in chip selector reactjs

Tags: error-handling

I have tags I want to filter my Card that card have particular  tags using material ui select chip - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#chip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.includes takes string as first argument. You cannot use array in that place.

introduce a search function

```
const findSelectedTag = (entry) => {
    for (let tag of selectedTags) {
      if (entry.tags.includes(tag)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  };
```

call it inside your filter function

```
const filteredEnteries = entries.filter((entry) => findSelectedTag(entry));
```